# Как вынести часть проекта в библиотеку?

Tags: makefile, g++, c++

Мне достался вот такой makefile

```
CPP=g++
CPPFLAGS= -g3 -Wall -lpthread

EXECUTOR=executor

LIBRARY_SRC= \
        share/builder.cpp \
        share/list.cpp \
        share/tree.cpp
        ...

all: engine

engine: $(EXECUTOR)

$(EXECUTOR): $(LIBRARY_SRC) executor.cpp
    @$(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $?

clean:
    -rm -rf $(EXECUTOR)
```

Список файлов LIBRARY_SRC довольно длинный. Как в make-файле выделить всю эту группу файлов в отдельную библиотеку, чтобы не пересобирать их каждый раз?

Answer (score 4):

Как-то вроде этого

```
CFLAGS = -I../../inc
EXECUTOR=executor

SRC = base64.c getline.c parseflg.c

LIB = tlib.a

all: engine

engine: $(EXECUTOR)

$(EXECUTOR): $(LIB) executor.o
        gcc $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $?

$(LIB): base64.o getline.o parseflg.o
        ar -r $(LIB) $?

%.o : %.c
        gcc $(CFLAGS) -c $<

clean:
        rm -f  ${LIB} *.o *.exe a.out *~ *.bak *.BAK
```

Я попробовал на примере своего кусочка, просто чтобы удостовериться, что библиотека
и $(EXECUTOR) в одном оглавлении будут нормально собираться. Вы подставьте свои команды, пути и флаги для сборки.

Все вроде живет, только объектники убрать не получилось, будут тут болтаться. Обратите внимание, в правило сборки $(EXECUTOR) я вместо executor.c прописал executor.o, т.к. из-за общего правила сборки .o из .c executor.o все равно будет создаваться.

Почитайте http://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/make_compile/ здесь неплохо, но на английском я встречал лучше и тоже Столлмана, только вот найти не могу.

Вообще, у себя, я библиотеки в отдельных каталогах собираю, но получается имею некое 'дерево' Makefiles.

**UPD**

Я подумал, что возможно у Вас проект, в котором действительно (по каким-то соображениям) требуется делать executor всегда из исходника, а его .o файла в каталоге быть не должно. Иначе странно, почему так написан исходный Makefile. Это решается, только правило надо написать такое:

```
 $(EXECUTOR): executor.c $(LIB) 
        gcc $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

Заодно, если требуется, чтобы в Винде тоже работало, пишите:

```
...
EXE =
ifdef WINDIR
EXE = .exe
endif
...
EXECUTOR=executor$(EXE)
...
```

Это не очень красиво, но как по другому написать переносимый в зависимости от наличия расширения у исполняемого модуля Makefile, я не знаю. Искал, но никаких решений не нашел.

Answer (score 0):

Пересобираться будет в любом случае. Вопрос в целесообразности. Имея опыт с make, скажу вот что, пусть там будет помойка, но вы ее видеть не должны, именно для этого создается Makefile. Чтобы один раз сделать и потом пользоваться программой make. Главное чтобы все было структурировано.